# How te display delete button from a TODO list

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, onmouseover

I am making a todo list and i have a function that display (it adds opacity) the delete button when i have the mouse over the correspondant Li.

```
  todosUl.addEventListener("mouseover", function(event) {
  var elementHovered = event.target;
  var deleteButton = document.getElementById("deleteButton"+elementHovered.id)
  deleteButton.style.opacity=1;
  });
  todosUl.addEventListener("mouseout", function(event) {
  var elementHovered = event.target;
  var deleteButton = document.getElementById("deleteButton"+elementHovered.id)
  deleteButton.style.opacity = 0;
  });
```

the problem is that whenever I approach the area of the button, the button dissapears again. 
when this happens, the console shows this: Cannot read property 'style' of null

this is how i created the Li :

```
todoLi.appendChild(view.createDeleteButton(position));

createDeleteButton: function (liId) {
    var deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
    deleteButton.textContent = 'X';
    deleteButton.className = 'deleteButton';
    deleteButton.id = 'deleteButton'+liId;
    return deleteButton;
```

Comment: Could you also please included the relevant HTML?

Comment: sure! there i added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any particular reason you need the js for this rendering? Below is an html/css model

```css
.delete {
  opacity: 0;
}
li:hover > .delete {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul id="toDos">
  <li>To Do Item 1<input type="button" class="delete" value="Delete"/></li>
  <li>To Do Item 2<input type="button" class="delete" value="Delete"/></li>
  <li>To Do Item 3<input type="button" class="delete" value="Delete"/></li>
  <li>To Do Item 4<input type="button" class="delete" value="Delete"/></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` instead of `mouseover` and `mouseout` events.

```js
var todosUl = document.getElementById("todoitem1");
todosUl.addEventListener("mouseenter", function(event) {
  var elementHovered = event.target;
  var deleteButton = document.getElementById("deleteButton"+elementHovered.id)
  deleteButton.style.opacity=1;
  });
  todosUl.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(event) {
  var elementHovered = event.target;
  var deleteButton = document.getElementById("deleteButton"+elementHovered.id)
  deleteButton.style.opacity = 0;
  });
```

```html
<div id='todoitem1' width='100%' style='background-color: yellow'>
  <button id="deleteButtontodoitem1" style='opacity: 0'>Delete</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you run the code snippet? it is showing the button on mouse enter and hide it on mouse leave...and no JS errors